# Windows API for moving a window to a specific monitor

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-10

Suppose the computer has two monitors: Mon1 and Mon2. Notepad is on Mon2. I know the handle of its window. Can I move the window from Mon2 to Mon1 programmatically? What Windows API should I use? I have found the following candidates, but their documentation does not mention monitors.

```
SetWindowPos
SetWindowPlacement
MoveWindow
```

If anyone is interested in why I am trying to do this, this is because sometimes I need to move a window from Mon2 to Mon1 while the window is obscured by a full-screen always-on-top window or Mon2 is turned off.

Comment: Monitors exist on a single coordinate space, an app does not technically belong to any one monitor. `EnumDisplayMonitors` + `GetMonitorInfo` should give you the coordinates of each monitor, then call `SetWindowPos` to move it to whichever you want.

Comment: Thank you. I can now do what I wanted. Also, I have found that there is `System.Windows.Forms.Screen` in C# that I can use instead of the two display API's.

Comment: The system has shortcuts to do this. You don't need to replicate them.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Doing something programmatically and using system shortcuts are orthogonal.

Comment: It might be considered helpful to point out that these shortcuts exist in case the asker is not aware of them.

Comment: Thank you, Mr David Hueffernan. I almost completed creating my own application, but then I saw your comment and found that there was a shortcut [Windows] + [Shift] + [Left] (first select the window from the Task View or from Task Manager, even if it is invisible). I would have not tried to create an application, if I knew this existed.

Comment: That happens if you mix questions with proposed solutions. You have asked about your solution, not the problem you were trying to solve. Had you posted a question about your problem (e.g. on Super User), you would have received the correct answer, and maybe even contributed to this Q&A network. As things turned out, this is just noise.